lists, peek operations and microtype trouble
LaTeX's peek operations are a bit of a black box for me and I'm struggle to get microtype protrusion to behave in a custom list which has a peek operation at the beginning of it.
The following silly MWE reproduces my problem. I'd like all the quotation marks to line up. I hoped that inserting \leftprotrusion before I put the token back on the input stream with \peek_analysis_map_break:n would work, but sadly it does not.
I guess this is because I don't really understand \peek_analysis_map_inline:n and so the \leftprotrusion is not inserted where I think it will be.
As pointed out by @cfr in the comments, what I have mostly works. It's the combination of pdflatex and the UTF-8 “ that fails. I'm after an engine agnostic solution.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{microtype}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\bool_new:N \l__dcp_zzz_bool
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__dcp_peek:
  {
    \peek_remove_spaces:n
      {
        \peek_analysis_map_inline:n
          {
            \exp_args:No \token_if_eq_meaning:NNT { ##1 } \zzz
              {
                \bool_set_true:N \l__dcp_zzz_bool
                \cs_set_eq:NN \zzz \leftprotrusion
                \peek_analysis_map_break:n { ##1 }
              }
              \peek_analysis_map_break:n
                {
                  \cs_if_exist_use:N \leftprotrusion
                  ##1
                }
          }
      }
  }
\NewDocumentEnvironment { test } { }
  {
    \cs_set_eq:NN \zzz \relax
    \list{}{}
    \item
      \relax
      \__dcp_peek:
  }
  {
    \bool_if:NT \l__dcp_zzz_bool { $\circ$ }
    \endlist
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\parindent 0pt
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{test}
  \zzz
  “

  “
\end{test}

\begin{test}
  \zzz
  \leftprotrusion
  “

  “
\end{test}

\begin{test}
  “ $\leftarrow$ this one is wrong

  “
\end{test}

\begin{test}
  \leftprotrusion
  “

  “
\end{test}
\end{document}




Engine? I'm guessing pdfTeX. I think the problem is to do with the way the unicode character is encoded. In LuaTeX, the quotation marks are aligned. If you redefine \leftprotrusion, LuaTeX doesn't complain, but pdfTeX will complain about an unrecognised Unicode character ("80). If you replace the opening double quotation mark by two back ticks, the problem also disappears in pdfTeX. So I guess when you peek ahead you're picking up the first bit of a character that needs multiple-bits to encode it, as it does in pdfTeX. But I'm probably completely wrong. Sorry. code would explain better.

@cfr you are exactly right. In fact my code in the question fixes my problem. I just happened to run the tests with pdflatex and a utf-8 character. I have a feeling getting it to behave in this case might be tricky. (And you might as well read impossible for me.)

I don't even understand other people's code if it peeks, so I was curious to play with a simple example. But I know a (very) little bit about the font stuff ;).

In the last map_break function, ##1 is actually the token enclosed in \unexpanded. You need to expand it once for \leftprotrusion to see the real token, or you could write \l_peek_token instead of ##1.

Another idea: Instead of trying to integrate \leftprotrusion into your peek function, you could conversely make \leftprotrusion aware of it -- with \g@addto@macro\MT@prot@check@cmds{{S\__dcp_peek:}}, your peek function will be executed without blocking \leftprotrusion's view of the next character.

Thanks @Robert, using \l_peek_token works well. I've struggle to find good examples of using \peek_analysis_map_inline:n and the documentation is a bit thin for someone who is not an expert.

@Robert if you add an answer with one or both of your suggestions, I'll accept it.
